# Multiple plupload upload buttons with one plupload call

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I have a plupload call:

```
$("#cni, #kbis, #rcpro").pluploadQueue({
runtimes: "html5, flash",
url: "ajax.php?action=x",
max_file_size: "2mb",
chunk_size: "1mb",
multiple_queues: true,
multi_selection: false,
multipart_params: {"u_id": "<?php echo $si_r['u_id']; ?>"},
//filters: [{title : "Files", extensions : ""}],
flash_swf_url: "js/plupload.flash.swf",

init:{

BeforeUpload: function(up, file){
alert(this.attr("id"))
}

}


});
```

it calls this html:

```
<div justif="cni" id="cni"></div>
<div justif="kbis" id="kbis"></div>
<div justif="rcpro" id="rcpro"></div>
```

what i am trying is each time i click each plupload button to call a specific variable in this case the id attribute:

```
BeforeUpload: function(up, file){
alert(this.attr("id"))
}
```

but it does not work, anyone has an idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I set a cookie on client side:

```
 $("#cni, #kbis, #rcpro").click(function(){
 $.cookie("justif", $(this).attr("id"));
 })
```

then collect it on server side.